# How to get context from higher order component in constructor of child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following context provider to give me access to context across the application:

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react';
import { appInitialization, Context } from "@microsoft/teams-js";
import TeamsContextService from '../Services/TeamsContextService';
import Constants from '../Constants/AppConstants';

const TeamsContext = React.createContext({});

interface Error {
    status: boolean,
    message: appInitialization.IFailedRequest
}

interface TeamsContextProviderState {
    teamsContext : any,
    error?: Error
}

class TeamsContextProvider extends Component<{}, TeamsContextProviderState> {
    getContext: Function
    state: TeamsContextProviderState = {
        teamsContext: {},
        error: undefined
    }

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.getContext = TeamsContextService();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getContext()
            .then((context: Context) => {
                const frameContext = context.frameContext || "";
                if (frameContext === Constants.Surfaces.SidePanel) {
                    this.setState({
                        teamsContext: context,
                    })
                    appInitialization.notifySuccess();
                    return;
                }
                return Promise.reject("Error: Please make sure to run the app within teams as a tab app");
            })
            .catch((msg: appInitialization.IFailedRequest) => {
                appInitialization.notifyFailure(msg);
                this.setState({
                    error: {
                        status: true,
                        message: msg,
                    }
                })
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TeamsContext.Provider value={this.state.teamsContext}>
                {this.props.children}
            </TeamsContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default TeamsContextProvider;

export const withTeamsContext = (Component: any) => (props: any) => {
    const teamsContext = useContext(TeamsContext);
    return <Component {...props} teamsContext={teamsContext} />
}
```

This is used by the main application as such:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
            <TeamsContextProvider>
                <SurfaceSelector/>
            </TeamsContextProvider>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Inside the `SurfaceSelector` child component I would like to get access to the `TeamsContextProvider` `teamsContext` prop. However in the constructor of `SurfaceSelector` it is returning `undefined` for its child properties. But once it reaches the `render` function of surface selector then the `teamsContext` is correctly populated. I would like to use the `theme` property on the `teamsContext` to update the currently selected theme, but I can't do that in the constructor because it is undefined and in the render I won't be able to set state without causing an infinite loop. What's a work around to this? I tried the `componentDidUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate`, and other react lifecycle methods but they all end up with an infinite loop if I try to update the state. I tried `useContext` but I cannot do that in the `SurfaceSelector` component because it is a class component and needs state to manage the theme.

Here is `SurfaceSelector`

```
import { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import SidePanelPage from '../Pages/SidePanel';
import { withTeamsContext } from '../Contexts/TeamsContextProvider';
import Constants from '../Constants/AppConstants';
import { Context, registerOnThemeChangeHandler } from '@microsoft/teams-js';
import { Provider, teamsDarkV2Theme, teamsHighContrastTheme, ThemeInput} from '@fluentui/react-northstar'
import { i18n } from '@lingui/core'
import { I18nProvider } from '@lingui/react'
import { defaultLocale, dynamicActivate } from '../i18n'

export interface SurfaceSelectorProps {
    teamsContext: Context
}

interface SurfaceSelectorState {
    theme?: ThemeInput<any>
}

class SurfaceSelector extends Component<SurfaceSelectorProps, SurfaceSelectorState> {
    constructor(props: SurfaceSelectorProps) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            theme: this.getTheme(this.props.teamsContext.theme)
        }
    }

    private getTheme(theme?: string) {
        switch (theme) {
            case "dark":
                return teamsDarkV2Theme;
            case "contrast":
                return teamsHighContrastTheme;
        }
        return teamsDarkV2Theme;
    }

    render() {
        const { SidePanel } = Constants.Surfaces;
        const frameContext = this.props.teamsContext.frameContext;
        switch (frameContext) {
            case SidePanel:
                return (
                    <Fragment>
                        <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
                            <Provider theme={this.state.theme}>
                                <SidePanelPage />
                            </Provider>
                        </I18nProvider>
                    </Fragment>
                )
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

export default withTeamsContext(SurfaceSelector);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've rewrote your code to understand what you were doing, as I finished it just works.

It is way too cleaner than yours, so it would be easier to find out what you are missing.

Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-leakey-brp0g?file=/src/SurfaceSelector.js:169-262)

Comment: Hmm looking at the console in your link, it says that teams context is still an empty object. Should it not have a value of foo within it?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same issue where by the props are available in the render but not in the constructor of the SurfaceSelector. I see  {teamscontext: { foo: 1}} in render but not in the constructor :(

Comment: You just needs to set the object in the constructor of context, changed the sandbox

Comment: So if we look at ComponentDidUpdate in the Context and change the setState to 0 then the value doesn't show as 0 in the constructor of SurfaceSelector, it still only shows 1. Since I am performing work in componentDidUpdate I would need the change to be reflected down into the constructor of SurfaceSelector.